# @ManyToOne with count and sub query with criteria builder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I need to execute the following query using criteria builder (get the list of announcements and whether the user added this announcement to favourites).

```
@Entity
class FavouriteAnnouncement(
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) var announcement: Announcement? = null,
    var userId: Long? = null
) : BaseEntity()

@Entity
class Announcement(
    var title: LocalizedString? = null,
    var categoryId: Long? = null,
    var location: Location? = null,
    var sum: String? = null,
    var primaryPhotoHashId: String? = null,
    var promotionOrder: Int = 0
) : BaseEntity()
```

The custom query that I need is the following:

```
select id,
       created_date,
       latitude,
       longitude,
       primary_photo_hash_id,
       promotion_order,
       sum,
       en,
       ru,
       uz_cyr,
       uz_lat,
       (select count(fa.announcement_id) as favourite_count
        from favourite_announcement fa
        where a.id = fa.announcement_id
          and a.deleted = false
          and user_id = 6)
from announcement a
where deleted = false
  and category_id = 1
  and promotion_order in (0, 1, -1)
order by created_date desc,
         promotion_order desc;
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial on the JPA Criteria API that you can use to learn how to write such queries: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html